# Send email under Magento with out template

Tags: php, e-commerce, magento

Hello I have been trying to send an email in magento with out a template and just from the Zend framework.  So far I have not got one email.  Here is what I have.

```
define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
$new_stock_csv ="var/import/test.co/new_stock.csv";

require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';
$currentStore = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(); 

$mess = "Test of message to be in body."
product_change_email($mess,MAGENTO.$new_stock_csv);

function product_change_email($mess,$file){ 
    $fromEmail = "notice@gmail.com";
    $fromName = "PRODUCT ALERTS";
    $toEmail = "jeremybass@somewhere.net";
    $toName = "Jeremy Bass";
    $body = $mess;
    // body text
    $subject = "Test Subject";
    // subject text

    try{
        $mail = new Zend_Mail();
        $mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);
        $mail->addTo($toEmail, $toName);
        $mail->setSubject($subject);
        $mail->setBodyHtml($body); // here u also use setBodyText options.

        // this is for to set the file format
        $at = new Zend_Mime_Part($body);

        $at->type        = 'application/csv'; // if u have PDF then it would like -> 'application/pdf'
        $at->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;
        $at->encoding    = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_8BIT;
        $at->filename    = $file;
        $mail->addAttachment($at);
        $mail->send();

    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMassage();

    }
}
```

Comment: 'So far I have not got one email' -- meaning what? Anything in your Magento/Apache/Postfix error logs?

Comment: No message in any log, and not echoing anything.  Magento does send internal email, but I can't seem to get this function to work.  Thanks -

Comment: What operating system are you running this script on? Do you have PostFix installed correctly and configured? What is internal email?

Comment: it's on CentOs 6.x under php 5.3.2 . um.. not sure on the postfix and the email is a smtp externally hosted.  All emails thru Magento appear to be working too.  Thanks -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post fix was not installed correctly.  tk Zachary Schuessler